# Approximating function using taylors formula

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$.  I want to use a $2$-degree polynome about $x=0$, $P_2(x)$, to approximate the function $f(x)$ on the interval $I = [-0.4, 0.4]$.

The problem is to find the smallest constant $c$, such that $|f(x)-P_2(x)| \leq c$

I found that the  taylorseries for $f(x)$  is $1+x+x^2$ (stopping when i reach 2-degree polynome).

Now I found that $g(x) = f(x)-(1+x+x^2)$ = $\frac{-x^3}{x-1}$

g(0.4) then gives me 8/75. $|f(x)-P_2(x)|$ will never exceed this value as long as $x \leq 0.4$. But my answer is wrong, does someone see why?

Comment: It seems you read the problem literally by finding the maximum value of the difference between $f$ and $P_2$ on $[-0.4,0.4]$.  But you didn't use Taylor's formula.  That formula gives explicit upper bounds on this remainder, involving higher derivatives.  Could that be the intended solution?

Comment: Here is the question that you may want to follow per @MatthewLeingang advice, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415430/find-reasonable-upper-bound-on-error-in-approximating-taylor-series-fx-sin5

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize I had to use the formula for the error $E_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(s)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{(n+1)}$. Do you have any hints as to how I have to apply this formula, I don't really understand what they're looking for

Comment: What do you suppose $f$, $n$, $x$, and $a$ are in the context of this problem?

Comment: I'm thinking n=2, a=0 but i realize that plugging this and the third derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ just gives me $x^3$ ... Is $f$ equal to the third derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ here?

Comment: Any advice? (bump)